# How can I increase a cleric's channel energy ability without taking more cleric levels?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, channel-energy

I am playing a [cleric](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric)/[wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard)/[Mystic Theurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge). Is there a way to increase the cleric's channeled energy ability while taking levels in other classes?

None of the [channel energy feats](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/channeling-feats/) do this.

I am aware of [Phylactery of Positive Channeling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/phylactery-of-positive-channeling/) which increases channel by +2d6.

Answer (score 1):

## [Variant Multiclass Cavalier](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Cavalier&Category=Base%20Classes) with [Order of the star](https://www.aonprd.com/CavalierOrders.aspx?ItemName=Order%20of%20the%20Star)

Through VMC Cavalier, you get:

> Order Ability: At 7th level, he gains the 2nd-level ability of his chosen order, treating his character level as his effective cavalier level.

The order of the star 2nd level ability states:

> Calling (Ex): At 2nd level, the cavalier can make a short prayer as a standard action, filling him with confidence in his abilities. At any point in the next minute, he can receive a competence bonus on an ability check, attack roll, saving throw, or skill check equal to his Charisma modifier. He must declare that he is using this bonus before the roll is made. He can use this ability up to four times per day, once for each type of check or roll. **In addition, the cavalier adds 1/2 his cavalier level to any levels of paladin or cleric he might possess for the purposes of determining the effects of *channel energy* or lay on hands.**

This would increase your channel energy by 1/2 your level, stacking with the cleric levels you already have, as you take your wizard and Mystic Theurge levels.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I get the sense that the question is likely specifically asking about Wizard and Mystic Theurge, rather than other classes entirely.

Comment: @YogoZuno I mean, sure, but variant multiclassing allows you to take only wizard/Cleric/MT levels.

Comment: Sorry, I clearly didn't understand you could mix VMC with normal MC.

Comment: Right. It's effectively trading feats for class features, not a "true" multiclass.